# How to choose flyout menu item in c# metro style app

Tags: c#, windows, window, windows-store-apps

I want to select each and every item of menu flyout items . Basically I want to choose an item from the code-behind and perform functionality on it.

```
<AppBarButton  x:Name="Resize" Click="resizeop_click"HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Second command" />
            <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
            <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Last option" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
    <AppBarSeparator>
    </AppBarSeparator>
</AppBarButton>
```

Following C# function

```
private void resizeop_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Not Working 
   Resize.Flyout.GetValue = "1";
   // How Should i select Each Item in code here?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get MenuFlyoutItem like this:
using index:

```
((Resize.Flyout as MenuFlyout).Items[0] as MenuFlyoutItem).Text = "hello world";
```

this code can set text from "1" to "hello world".

Comment: You are welcome.please mark it as answer so more people can get it easier.